# Why is the potential energy of a suspended rope proportional to the stretch?

Tags: classical-mechanics, potential-energy, string

In A. Zee Einstein Gravity in a Nutshell, when he is talking about variational calculus on page 113, he gives an example of a suspended rope.

To calculate the total potential energy due to tension, it's sufficient to know the energy stored in an infinitesimal piece $dx$ then integrate.

A. Zee then proceeds to say that the potential energy due to tension is:

$$U= T\left(\sqrt{dx^2 + d\phi^2} - dx\right)$$

where $T$ is a proportionality constant, and $\phi$ is the hight of the rope. My problem is shouldn't the energy be proportional to the distance *squared*?

Shouldn't the potential energy be:

$$U=\frac{1}{2}T\left(\sqrt{dx^2 + d\phi^2} - dx\right)^2$$
analogous to:

$$U= \frac{1}{2} k x^2$$

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that the force in consideration here, that is tension, does not follow Hooke's law (Force $\propto$ extension) and is a constant. In such a case work done by tension for extension will be equal to the Tension $\times$ Extension in the rope.

Answer (score 0):

Could the rope already be under tension, before it is allowed to sag?
In this case the *extra* tension associated with the sagging might be negligible compared with the original tension ($T_0$ say), so the work done on the portion during the sagging by the tension would simply be given by Zee's formula in which the constant $T$ is $T_0$.

Comment: I don't know if that's what you meant, but what is given is that the rope was stretched till it became straight at first.

Comment: Presumably the rope is 'now' hanging in a curve (a catenary). Is it held at each end? Or have I misunderstood the set-up? My answer was based on the rope being stretched (perhaps while lying on a table) and then supported only at each end, perhaps from clamps at the same horizontal level as each other.